# rank of 4x4 matrix f(A) is

Tags: minimal-polynomials

Let f(x) be the minimal polynomial of the 4x4 matrix A equal to

0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0

Then rank of the 4x4 matrix f(A) is

[image]

Comment: Would you please edit the question to include the definition of *minimal polynomial of a matrix* (so that you too may see the tautology)?

Comment: Going a little step further in Sassatelli's comment's direction: what the minimal, and the characteristic, polynomial do to the matrix is **a matrix equality** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From definition of minimal polynomial, we have

$$f(A)=0$$.

Are you able to compute its rank?